# Are there namespaces for Swift Playgrounds?

Tags: swift2, swift-playground

In the process of learning Swift I am creating Playgrounds per topic (e.g. one for Structures etc.) and I keep adding snipplets of concepts I learn along the way.

My problem is I usually use variable names like a,b,c.... but it is cumbersome to avoid having duplicate name errors. So I was wondering if there is a way to declare namespace blocks.

My playground (not the real topics, just for illustration):

```
// topic 1 blah
var a = 1
var b = 2
a + b

// topic 2 blah blah
var a = 5
var b = 3
a / b
```

One work around is to add a function block around it:

```
func example1() {
    ...
}
```

But is there a better way? Blocks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **do** statement:

```
do {
var a = 1
var b = 2
print(a+b)
}

do {
var a = 3
var b = 5
print(a / b)
}
```

Comment: Thank you! that will do.

Answer (score 0):

As noted, the `do` statement lets you create a scope.

But you can also use the new multi-page playgrounds in Xcode 7 — each page runs separately, so you can reuse the same variable names in each. And you can also make source files that are preloaded and shared by multiple pages.